# How can i insert value into a table with foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1452

I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lfPt.jpg) scheme for tables

And i can't insert any value into a second or 3d table at all becouse of error 1452 (cannot add or update a child row.)
How can i insert something? (not useing a SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;)

Comment: *I have this scheme for tables* Provide it as complete CREATE TABLE textual scripts.

Comment: It's because your data model is broken. You can't have 2 tables that reference each other in this way: with an FK on each one referencing the PK on the other. Such a design makes no logical sense and, as you've discovered, there is no way to insert data into them - as each table would require there to be data in the other before data can be inserted into it

Comment: there IS a way, my teacher told me it is possible, but don't told me how

Comment: Show the model. Maybe it can be remodeled to avoid the circular dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have cyclic foreign keys reference than you cannot insert data directly - insertion into any table fails due to foreign key violation, and insertion in more than one table per one query not supported.

The solution: insert into first table but set referencing column to NULL, insert into second table, update first table.

Example:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test1 (t1_id INT PRIMARY KEY, t2_id INT);
> CREATE TABLE test2 (t1_id INT, t2_id INT PRIMARY KEY);
> ALTER TABLE test1 ADD FOREIGN KEY (t2_id) REFERENCES test2 (t2_id);
> ALTER TABLE test2 ADD FOREIGN KEY (t1_id) REFERENCES test1 (t1_id);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (1,11);
> ```
>
> ```
> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_262184466`.`test1`, CONSTRAINT `test1_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`t2_id`) REFERENCES `test2` (`t2_id`))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (1,11);
> ```
>
> ```
> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_262184466`.`test2`, CONSTRAINT `test2_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`t1_id`) REFERENCES `test1` (`t1_id`))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (1,NULL);
> INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (1,11);
> UPDATE test1 SET t2_id = 11 WHERE t1_id = 1;
> SELECT * FROM test1; 
> SELECT * FROM test2;
> ```
>
> ```
> t1_id | t2_id
> ----: | ----:
>     1 |    11
>
> t1_id | t2_id
> ----: | ----:
>     1 |    11
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=30ebc66c9d4537416d7bcb3421095a2d)*

Comment: It's still a really bad database design and is almost certainly incorrect if it's meant to be modelling any real world situation. Your teacher would be better spending their time setting real world challenges rather than theoretical, and pointless, ones like this - IMO!

Comment: @NickW *It's still a really bad database design* I agree with this statement. *if it's meant to be modelling any real world situation.* Life is much more diverse than the wildest fantasy...